# Contents of RecyclerView is not visible after setting VISIBLE for the first time. ( This code was working fine with v4-25.0.1)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

The code below was working fine with support-v4:25.0.1, but it doesn't work on all versions above up to 25.4.0.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2iMWgp2G2KHOE05NTIzal9iR0U/view?usp=sharing) is very small sample project demonstrating the issue

**When activity is opened for the first time, visibility of the Recyclerview is set to GONE**

[image: Opening activity for the first time]

**(Bug is here) After switching to the TAB 2 for the first time, contents of the Recylcerview is not visible.**

[image]

**Going back to the TAB 1 and again to the TAB 2 will reveal contents of the Recyclerview.**

[image]

Do you have any solutions how to make it work using support v4 25.4.0?

**dependencies.gradle**

```
//final SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '25.0.1' // last working version
final SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '25.4.0'

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION}"
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <import type="android.text.TextUtils" />
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/stockmedia_cc_dsd_8910"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_1"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_2"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/content_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
        binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(this));
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        boolean firstTabVisible = tab.getPosition() == 0;
        binding.nestedScrollView.setVisibility(!firstTabVisible ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        binding.recyclerView.setVisibility(firstTabVisible ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

**Posible Workaround**

One of the possibles workarounds is to postpone setting Visibility.GONE on the Recyclerview until it becomes visible. But I don't like this solution and **I think this should be fixed in support-v4 lib**.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
        binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
        binding.recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                updateTabVisibility();
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
                    binding.recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    binding.recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(this));
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        updateTabVisibility();
    }

    private void updateTabVisibility() {
        boolean firstTabVisible = binding.tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 0;
        binding.nestedScrollView.setVisibility(!firstTabVisible ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        binding.recyclerView.setVisibility(firstTabVisible ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with Lib version. The issue is with your code. As far as I can see even if you revert back to the previous Lib version, it still won't work. Try it!
Now come to point the issue is your Recyclerview's visibility is "GONE" by default; becuase you have set it to gone in your XML file. And you are making it visible in your "OnTabSelected" method. So untill you won't change the tabs it won't show up. All you have to do is just remove  this  line (android:visibility="gone") from your Recyclerview object in your XML file.
Hope it'll work for you!

Comment: This code does work on support v4:25.0.1. Have you tried to compile & run the sample project I provided? This [giphy](https://media.giphy.com/media/xUPGcLNpeG7wdVnala/giphy.gif) shows how app behaves compiled with version 25.0.1

Comment: No I haven't, but I will. Actually I am bust in some work right now. But I'll check it and will get back to you. Till then you try  the solution I posted.